# How to create dynamic schema in database using asp.net mvc and entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, database-schema

how can i create dynamic schema in database(sql server/postgresql) using MVC and Entity Framework.

For example : when sign-up to the application, create schema and table in database.

Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtGVk.jpg)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

Comment: EF creates it by default when using CodeFirst